# Angular frequency. Wrong interpretation at Wikipedia?

Tags: waves, frequency

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave) articles mention that the angular frequency is:

```
number of oscillations per unit of time
```

But this doesn't seem to be correct since the angular frequency is the *speed of wave rotation*, and Wiki actually says about the *wave frequency*. Is this correct or I simply don't understand something?

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is an implicit factor of $2\pi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If something does a complete rotation per second, everyone agrees it has an angular frequency of 2π radians per second.  It is well-known that one complete oscillation is equal to the angle of 2π radians, so the article as written isn't necessarily wrong as 1 oscillation per second is equivalent to 2π radians per second (just different units).  However, it could possibly be clearer:

Angular frequency specifies the rate of angular change and is equal in value to 2π radians times the number of oscillations per unit of time.